# ASP.NET Core 2: UserManager vs. DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using the generic `IdentityUser<T>` class for my user model and with using `string` as primary key everything works fine, but I would like to use `long`as key type. So, I'm using the generic version of IdentityUser. Now I discovered that the UserManager has the following definition:

```
public class UserManager<TUser> : IDisposable where TUser : class
```

and the following function

```
public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId);
```

It seems that this doesn't fit together because the function requires a string as key/ID. `TUser` must be `TUser<TKey>`.

The question is now if there is any performance loss because of parsing string to long (of course there is) or is it better to get the user object direct from DbContext with a normal database select?
Does the UserManager has any benefits so that it would be recommended to use it even with the string key requirement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindByIdAsync` always takes string because it is a common denominator of every class. Instead of polluting with generics all over the place (like in Identity v2) you will have to convert your digits to string and pass it on. On DB side it is [handled by EF](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/87a956e49415581e3767d8de66a1f5a326f02194/src/EF/UserStore.cs#L234) anyway for you.

You can have your own UserManager class that inherits from `UserManager` and have a method override `FindByIdAsync(long id)` that just does `id.ToString()`

```
    public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(long userId)
    {
         return base.FindByIdAsync(userId.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: OK. I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your `User` table to use a different type for a primary key by extending the `IdentityUser` class like so:

`public class MyUser : IdentityUser<long>`

And then injecting `UserManager<MyUser>` into your classes to manage them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But the UserManager has no generics for the FindByIdAsync function. It's a static string parameter type. That's my problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize FindByIdAsync always accepted a string and assumed it would use `T`. I would still just convert the long to a string. I doubt the cost of conversion is worth losing the convenience of UserManager and other Identity classes.

Comment: I was surprised too. But it seems that UserManager should be "open" for any kind of user model, not only for IdentityUser<T>.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x) link you can see that it is possible to change type of the key. Initially it is set to string, so that you can use values like int or guid out of the box.

Code taken from mentioned link.
Firstly change your user to desired key type:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
 {
 }
```

Edit Application Role class:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long>
{
}
```

In application context class, add your new key:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long>
```

Comment: Note this is for legacy ASP.NET, not ASP.NET Core. Core works a bit differently: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: That's what I did. But it doen't change anything in UserManager's FindByIdAsync parameter.